# Making an "EnemyFactory"

Tags: iphone, class, cocos2d-iphone, factory, sprite

How can I make a new class that I can incorporate into my other Levels of my game that produces enemies? I'm using cocos2d btw. I would like to achieve the effect that I only have to do this.

```
[EnemyFactory enemyType:enemy amount:15];
```

Thanks!

EDIT - I'm trying to make a factory of sprites, that can produce them at a given time. Please read the comments

Comment: You make a new class by creating an interface and implementation for it. Typically in separate EnemyType.h and EnemyType.m files. If you want a static method called enemyType, declare it in the .h file and implement in .m file. That said, your question is impossible to answer. What exactly is your problem - you don't know how to create a class? You don't know how to implement the desired functionality? You're not sure about static methods?

Comment: My problem is  "You don't know how to implement the desired functionality? You're not sure about static methods?" Haha yeah you got it there. I know I'll need an enemyType and amount method, but how do I make the amount able to supply an int, and that int signals the amount of enemies? And what would you put in the enemyType method that would let you select a specific enemy?

Comment: -(void)enemyType:(Enemy *)enemy {
Would that be good for an opener....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your enemy.h

```
//import library
@interface EnemyFactory : NSObject {
//blah blah blah
}
-(void)initWithEnemy:(int)type amount:(int)amt
```

Your enemy.m

```
-(id)initWithEnemy:(int)type amount:(int)amt
{
self = [super init]
if(self)
{
for(int i = 0 ; i<amt; i++)
{
switch(type){
case 1:
//blah blah blah
break;
case 2:
//blah blah blah
break;
}
}
}
return self;
}
```

Your game call..

```
EnemyFactory* factory = [[EnemyFactory alloc]initWithEnemy:enemy amount:15];
[factory release];
```

Comment: Your declaration and definition of the `-initWithEnemy:amount:` method differ. Likewise, this is not a "factory" per se, but regular object instantiation and the class should be simply named (in this case) `Enemy`. In this case, the method would more appropriately be named `-initWithType:amount:`, but that's not what the OP wants.

Comment: Sorry, I know my question isn't very clear. I'm using cocos2d, so this wouldn't really pertain to me. Like I said I need a method that I can use in different Levels where I summon different enemies and the amount gets called. Why is it "(int)type"? But still, I can't use the specific code because I'm using cocos2d

Comment: it can be used for cocos2d code.. hmmm... type is int cos i am using switch case for different types of enemy..
i believe that this can achieve wad he wants.. haha.. =)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand that code very well (after the for call). Can you explain what switch does and how I can use it with classes?

Comment: I'm not familar with breaks and cases. What do I do inside the cases?

Comment: u want to programme games without knowing the basic programming??? I'm speechless.. I am using objective c codes... Do you even know how to create a class??

Comment: No, I'm not talking about making a class! I know it's probably basic obj-c, but I'm not working with that, I've briefly done breaks, but nothing with cases. I'm going to read http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/The_Objective-C_switch_Statement

Comment: So you want to create a game with a enemy factory without using a class? My bad.. my example was with using class objects. And your 1st line of your question said:How can I make a new class that I can incorporate into my other Levels of my game that produces enemies..

Comment: Sorry, we're getting confused here. I DO want to make a new class to create the factory, but I was answering your other question if I know how to make a class.

Comment: Ok i watched a really helpful video on switches, and I understand it now. It's sort of like else if, but a lot more specific and helpful. The one thing I don't get is, why is type an int? I know it has to be an int to do switches, but type will have to be a sprite that I pick.

Comment: For the amt, how do I make it so that the number is the amount produced? I can't make a specific case, can I?

Comment: oh.. ok... so you want to make a class but do not know how? ok.. sorry about that.. haha.. hmm... cause i assume that different enemies have differ properties... so in the class itself, passing in the type will load the sprite, stats of the enemy and so on... the amount, you can use a for loop to loop the amount of objects you would want to allocate.. email me at junxron@gmail.com.. easier for me to answer your questions..